# Putty closing after username on one

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, putty

something very strange puzzles me... I am trying to login on a server with Putty but as soon as I press enter after the username it closes.
It doesn't matter if the username exists on the server or not. It doesn't matter if I let Putty don't close the window on exit, the log file doesn't help either.
I am using Linux Mint 19.2, also tried to remove my .putty dir, no difference.
The same system I have on laptop and there it works fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Does it happen when trying to login on a specific server or any server? I mean if you try to connect to server A it works fine but not when trying to login on server B.

Comment: Which logs did you consult? Only putty or server logs, too? Is there anything useful in the logs of the server you're trying to connect?

Comment: I've tested some more, it seems to happen only with new servers. Like all setup in 2018 or later I can't connect. Servers from 2017 e.g. are working fine, but all are running on Ubuntu 18.04. So it doesn't make sense after all :(
Which server logs to check? Putty doesn't see anything.